# HA-Proxy and ACL for http-request deny

Tags: haproxy

Running ha-proxy 1.6.

Can someone please tell me why the ACL and http-request deny is not working?

I've tried mode http, mode tcp, end slash, no slash in path, a path_end, different network masks, one single ip, etc.  I can't get it working. There is just no access control.  I can reach the directory and files from anywhere.

```
global
  pidfile /var/run/haproxy.pid
  daemon

defaults
  mode tcp
  retries 5
  option redispatch
  option dontlognull
  option tcp-smart-accept
  option tcp-smart-connect


listen front-end
  bind xxx.xxx.xxx.xx1:80
  bind xxx.xxx.xxx.xx2:80
  mode http
  balance roundrobin
  option forceclose
  option http-server-close
  option forwardfor
  maxconn 2000
  timeout http-request 15s
  timeout connect 15s
  timeout server 60s
  timeout client 30s
  timeout http-keep-alive 15s
  acl network_allowed src xxx.xxx.xxx.xx5
  acl inside path_beg,url_dec -i /path/to/directory/
  http-request deny if inside !network_allowed 


  server 1 xxx.xxx.xxx.xx1:80 weight 10 SERVER1 check
  server 2 xxx.xxx.xxx.xx2:80 weight 10 SERVER2 check
  server 3 xxx.xxx.xxx.xx3:80 weight 15 SERVER3 check
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `-m beg`:

```
acl inside path_beg,url_dec -m beg -i /path/to/directory/
```

Also, what you are trying to achieve?
As I can see and verify your on my server: right now from `src xxx.xxx.xxx.xx5` you have access to everything while from other addresses you'll get `403` for `/path/to/directory`:

```
curl http://example.com/path/to/directory/
<html><body><h1>403 Forbidden</h1>
Request forbidden by administrative rules.
</body></html>
```

But if you add `OR` to your `http-request deny`:

```
http-request deny if inside OR !network_allowed
```

then you will get `403` from all addresses except `src xxx.xxx.xxx.xx5` and from this address you will get `403` for `/path/to/directory`
Which behaviour is right?

Comment: Fedor Dikanev, Thank you! The -m beg did it.  btw: I wanted to allow x5 access to everything, including /path/to/directory, and allow all others access to everything BUT /path/to/directory.  I really appreciate it.

Comment: I believe `path_beg,url_dec -m beg` is duplicative. You may change `path_beg` to `path`, so the final version would be: `path,url_dec -m beg`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this makes sense , but the idea is to restrict the processing for only  HA subnet

https://www.haproxy.com/blog/introduction-to-haproxy-acls/

#the main goal of this ACL is to deny access to backend if the request is not from HAproxy host subnet 192.168.1.0/24 , defined in blacklist as 192.168.1.0/24.
acl onlyhaprx01 path -i -m beg /
use_backend websrv if onlyhaprx01
http-request deny if [path -i -m beg /] !{src -f /etc/haproxy/blacklist.acl}

please help me to understand my errors.